# Why objects stored in Swift dictionaries don't die?

Tags: ios, dictionary, swift, automatic-ref-counting

I have made a ViewController for testing with code below

```
class SomeClass {

    init() {
        println("Some entity created")
    }

    deinit {
        println("Some entity released")
    }

}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var dict = [String: SomeClass]()

    @IBAction func buttonTouch(sender: UIButton) {
        var some = SomeClass()

        dict["1"] = some
        dict.removeValueForKey("1")
        dict = [String: SomeClass]()
    }

}
```

The problem is that the entity (*some*) stored in property *dict* will never receive *deinit* call. I see only "*Some entity created*". Is it right behaviour?

**EDITED:**

*It has been fixed in new Swift version*

Comment: Do you ever remove that key from the dictionary?  or remove the view controller (and thus the dictionary)?  The dictionary is going to keep a reference to that object as long as the key is in it, and the view controller is going to keep a reference to the dictionary as long as it is around.

Comment: are you testing this in an app, the REPL, or a playground?

Comment: I think it is a bug in current Swift implementation. Similar problem was mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24700178/retain-cycle-when-grabing-values-or-keys-from-dictionary-in-swift

Comment: I am testing this in app. This entity is alive after the UIViewController dies

Comment: try `dict["1"] = nil`

Comment: your example is working fine, I'm seeing both entity created and released messages

Comment: @user2727195 it was in older version